# Allowing users to add markers to google maps and getting the coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What i want to do is embed a map on my website and allow users to place markers on it (also if there is a way to control how many markers a user can put on the map?) and i also want to get the coordinates of these markers once they have been put on the map. From the documentation that i've read for google maps javascript api V3, i can place markers on the map myself, but i dont see a way to let users put them up on the map. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: i got the solution. I guess i was too hasty in posting this question :D. It there in the documentation with example code as well :D

Comment: post your solution as an answer and accept it for other people

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Source: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html
Scroll [down to accessing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?csw=1#EventArguments) arguments in UI events.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location, 
      map: map
  });

  map.setCenter(location);
}
```

Comment: This works, but I wonder if you figured out how to limit the number of markers the user can add.